# Html.ListBoxFor not showing values after display:none

Tags: html, css, razor

If the Div is displayed on page load, All listBoxFor's work fine. But if I only show div contents later (during a button click), the values are there, but you can not see them.  It's like the listBoxFor is still having display:none assigned to the text column.

```
<div id="ExtraFeatures" style="display: none>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Cp.SelectedValues, Model.Cp.Funders, new {id = "SelectFunder"})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Cp.SelectedDeptValues, Model.Cp.Departments, new {id = "SelectDepartment"})</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

function GetInvoices() {
        $("#ExtraFeatures").show();
}
```

when GetInvoices is called Div is seen, but none values in ListBoxFor's.  If display:none is removed, everything is shown correct.
Some Code has been removed for clairity

Comment: You need to include the code for handling the button click. Also, your style attribute is missing a closing quote.

Comment: The missing closing quote is just because of moving code, and style was not inline, just put it there to show.

Answer (score 0):

Debug razor, checks are passing valeu..

```
<div id="ExtraFeatures" style="display: none">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Cp.SelectedValues, Model.Cp.Funders, new {id = "SelectFunder"})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Cp.SelectedDeptValues, Model.Cp.Departments, new {id = "SelectDepartment"})</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove the display:none the ListBoxFor show all values, they don't if later I use $("#ExtraFeatures").show();

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, First I removed the display:none in the div and let the @Html.listBoxFor populate, then I entered 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ExtraFeatures").hide();
    });
Now all works as it should!